# Javascript form validation not working in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a bootstrap modal with a form, and I have custom JavaScript field validation and it's not working, I have tried the same in a normal page without the modal and it works perfectly.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
function validartitulo()
{
    var titulo = form.titulo;
    if (titulo.value == "") {
    document.getElementById("msgtit").innerHTML = "<font color='red'>Este campo é obrigatório.</font>";
    return false;
}
if(titulo.value.length <= 25){
    document.getElementById("msgtit").innerHTML = "";
    return true;
    }
        else if(titulo.value.length>25){
        document.getElementById("msgtit").innerHTML = "<font color='red'>O tamanho máximo é 25!</font>"; 
            return false;}
        }

       function validar(){
    if(validartitulo() && validarlink())
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

and the form :

```
 <form id="luForm" class="form-horizontal form-label-left input_mask"    name="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST"  action="videos/alt_vid2.php" onsubmit="return validar()">

<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label"><font color="black">Titulo: </font></label>  
   <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
   <div class="input-group">
   <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tag"></i> </span>
  <input  style='text-align:center;' name="titulo" value="<?php echo $lin['titulo']; ?>" class="form-control"  type="text" onblur="return validartitulo()">
    </div>
  <div id="msgtit"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

console error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
at validartitulo (eval at globalEval (jquery.min.js:2), <anonymous>:3:12)
at HTMLInputElement.onblur
```

Comment: where is you form close? and where is `validar` function?

Comment: Any js errors in console?  "Not working" rules out exactly one situation.

Comment: @James I edited my question with the console error

Comment: @Kuru I edited my question with the validar() code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, it was an uncaught error, so someone suggested to me to move the `<script>`, if it was in the `head`, to the `body`, thanks to all anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this:

```
function validartitulo()
```

Change it to:

```
function validartitulo(form)
```

And

```
<input  style='text-align:center;' name="titulo" value="<?php echo $lin['titulo']; ?>" class="form-control"  type="text" onblur="return validartitulo()">
```

Change it to:

```
 <input  style='text-align:center;' name="titulo" value="<?php echo $lin['titulo']; ?>" class="form-control"  type="text" onblur="return validartitulo(this.form)">
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I already solved it , it was a small error , I simply moved the <script> from the head to the body and it worked dunno why